# How to check if results matching criteria are the same or different

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets "Jobs" and "Invoices", in the sheet "Jobs" row A has job numbers, row C addresses and row O invoice numbers. In the "Invoices" sheet I have invoice numbers in row A I want a formula that will look in the sheet Jobs and tell me if all job numbers matching the invoice number have the same address or different addresses. If they are the same addresses I would like it to return the address or if there is more than one address I would like it to return "Multiple".

Comment: I couldnt think how to use any formula other than to return the number of matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula in your Invoices sheet, row 2 (copy down from there as required).

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A2,Invoices,0)),"Invoice not found in 'Jobs'",IF(COUNTIFS(Invoices,$A2,Addresses,INDEX(Addresses,MATCH($A2,Invoices,0),1))=COUNTIF(Invoices,$A2),INDEX(Addresses,MATCH($A2,Invoices,0),1),"Multiple"))
```

Note that I created named ranges as follows.

- `Invoices` = Jobs!$O$2:$O$1000
- `Addresses` = Jobs!$C$2:$C$1000

If you prefer, you can replace the names with the addresses in the formula. However, named ranges are not only shorter to write and easier to read, they are also easier to maintain. In case of changes you don't need to modify the formulas, only the range specifications.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your attempt, it doesnt seem to work though, I edited as needed and it does execute but is giving the answer multiple on a test. 
The test is 2 jobs at one address so it should display the address from Jobs sheets row c.

Comment: I re-tested the formula and it works perfectly. However, the formula and you don't seem to see eye to eye with regard to what constitutes the "same address".  Run the following test on your Jobs sheet. Presuming that you have the "same" address in C2 and C3 write this formula in any blank cell, `=C2=C3`. The formula will return FALSE if they are not identical.

Comment: Although Im now passed this Ive just seen this comment and have had a similar problem on another formula: I am working on a formula that relies on   data from a cell (the data is a word "paid", this word is generated by a formula, although the first formula is running fine and presents the word "paid" in the cell correctly, the second formula doesn't seem to see it when basing the formula on =IF(C1,"paid".....

Comment: This forum works on the principle of a single question per thread. If you got my formula working, the original thread should be closed by accepting the answer. Then, if you have a new question, start a new thread. More people will respond.

Comment: No I didn't get your formula working, and the answer I gave give clarity on why, the question has remained open so that others may offer me a solution and the reason your formula didn't work is of course relevant to this and not a new question. I therefore do not have a new question at the moment and can also not accept your answer, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Indeed your initial response to my formula was correctly pointing to a fault in it. I didn't read your comment carefully enough and apologise for that. The formula in the answer above was modified. I didn't test it extensively but believe that it now does what you expected of it.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I have for other reasons now decided to stick with my solution as I have found other valuable and needed use for the data in the hidden columns needed to fix this,